# Visual Studio Mac Deployment Failed to Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Trying to deploy a Xamarin Android App to an emulator running on a Mac fails with error "**Deployment Failed**" along with `Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: secure_mkdirs failed: Permission denied`

Update: The emulator was started by Android Studio.  When I try to start the emulator from Visual Studio Mac, I get error

`PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx]!`

Below is an excerpt from the **Deploying To Device** pad round about where the errors start showing

```
...
Synchronizing assemblies
    Synchronizing assemblies...
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:  Deployment failed
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000: Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: FailedToSynchronizeFastDevAssemblies ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: secure_mkdirs failed: Permission denied
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Util/AggregateAsyncResult.cs:72 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPushSyncItems (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Adb/AdbSyncClient.cs:1071 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbClientTaskExtensions.InnerInvoke (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult l) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbClientTaskExtensions.cs:256 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000: 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallAssemblies (System.String destinationPath, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00339] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:614 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallAssemblies (System.String destinationPath, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003b5] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:622 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.FastDevAsync (System.Boolean useExternal) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:514 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x004b0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:229 
        /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(618,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/287/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:123 
    Done building target "_Upload" in project "xamarinwrapper.csproj" -- FAILED.
    
    Done building project "xamarinwrapper.csproj" -- FAILED.
    
    Build FAILED.
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I reinstalled Visual Studio for Mac, and created a new emulator using the Visual Studio Device Manager, started the emulator from Visual Studio Device Manager and it works now.

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I do not think that reinstalling Visual Studio is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I reinstalled Visual Studio for Mac, and created a new emulator using the Visual Studio Device Manager, started the emulator from Visual Studio Device Manager and it works now.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer.